# Connect Node.js to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I was following a tutorial, and I've have some methods in a controller to get data from database in SQL Server. Typical CRUD methods, and in each method I've wrote

```
 let pool = await sql.connect(config);
```

I want to optimise the code and call this only once and not everytime in every method, so the connection will be established from the first time I run the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to create `.js` file and add two methods one to get the connection and the other one to close the pool.

Then you import the `.js`  file and use the functions.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-nodejs-sql-server-example/blob/master/src/data/index.js) from David Neal.

Comment: Your answer can be improved by changing a couple things. 

It appears the linked gist snippet is small enough to just inline in your answer. This is helpful in case it gets taken down later rendering the link unusable. Also, although adding this `js`  file and importing it and using it might solve the issue, a simplified version of the answer might emerge if you ask yourself why this snippet solves the problem.  The JavaScript client function creates a closure around the pool variable and treats it like a singleton instance every time the getConnection() method is called preventing multiple ca